# Allow executing files as program (java..)

Tags: permissions

Where can I find the allow to execute file as program option in the Default elementary OS loki File manager?
When I try to open a file such as jar using Java runtime a window comes up as '.......(filename) is not marked as executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `executable bit` at least for the owner. You can right-click on the file, select `Properties` from the menu and set `Execute` on the `Permissions` tab:
[image: set executable bit for owner]

This is the equivalent of the terminal command: `chmod u+x test.jar`